# how to use addHTML function in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Could you please let me know how to use addHTML function in jsPDF libraries. Am trying to convert a webpage as pdf. want to use the addHTML function. Let me know what parameters need to be passed to get the entire webpage converted as pdf with header, logos, body etc

Answer (score 34):

First, you have to include [jsPDF](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) library, and also [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) or [rasterizeHTML](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/).

Then, just create a jsPDF object and save to pdf the entire 'body' tag (or whatever):

```js
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<body>
    <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</body>
```

You can find more examples on the jsPDF website: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Comment: is it necessary to use document.body? Why can't I use document.getElementById() or something?

Comment: @BrianSchermerhorn It is not necessary to use document.body. You can pass any DOM element. Just make sure it is not the encapsulated jquery reference: `$("#target").get(0)` and not `$("#target")`

Comment: how to use multiple addhtml for header, body and footer ? please help me i am dying since two days..

Comment: I'm using jsPDF 2.1.1 (now latest) with angular, i get valid intellisense for addHTML method, but in runtime this throws 

TypeError: this.pdfCreator.addHTML is not a function

jsPDF.html( ) works fine, but i want to add other content after/before the html element and jsPDF.html( ) wont support that ... I would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of jsPDF, you can addHTML won't work, instead use

```
pdf.html(document.getElementById('gen-notes'), {
    callback: function (pdf) {
      pdf.save();
        },
    x: 100, // x position on the PDF document in jsPDF units.
    y: 100, // y position on the PDF document in jsPDF units.
  });
```

For more options refer to [jsPDF docs](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml)