# jsPdf set opacity

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, jspdf

Is there any way to set opacity for images and text in **jsPdf**. I was looking in the documentation didn't find any option to do that.
https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html

Snippet to add image to pdf is here
http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score -1):

Try using the jsPDF addHTML plugin. That way, you can style your images and text using HTML and CSS, and add it to the PDF using jspdf.addHTML. See [how to use addHTML function in jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193487/how-to-use-addhtml-function-in-jspdf). There's also an addHTML example in the link you posted (http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/).

Another option would be to edit the opacity of the image and text via drawing it on a canvas, [editing the opacity of the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen), then adding [the data URL of the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to the PDF using addImage.