# HTML to pdf export isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Trying to export a section of a html page (shopping basket) isn't working. I'm getting no error logs but the page is only refreshing, nothing else happens. I'm trying to export the shopping basket to a pdf and retain some of its styling information, preferably in a tabular format to act as an invoice

Html

```
    <div id="contentStart">
  <!--START: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item-info">
      <div class="product-image"><!--START: itemthumbnail--><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]"><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" /></a><!--END: itemthumbnail--><!--START: thumbnailnolink--><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" id="tnl" /><!--END: thumbnailnolink--></div>
      <div class="product-name-options"> 
        <!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" class ="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink--> 
        <!--START: itemnamenolink--><span id="spnItemName">[ITEM_NAME]</span><!--END: itemnamenolink--> 
        <!--START: itemoptions--> 
        <br />
        <a href='#' onclick="toggle('opt[ITEM_ID]')">View/Hide options</a><br />
        <div id=opt[ITEM_ID] name=opt[ITEM_ID] style="display:none;">[OPTIONS]</div>
        <!--END: itemoptions--> 
        <!--START: recurring_frequency-->
        <div class="recurring_frequency">This item will Autoship every <strong>[recurring_frequency]</strong></div>
        <!--END: recurring_frequency--> 
        <!--START: giftwraplink-->
        <div class="giftwraplink"> <a onclick="showGiftWrap('[ITEM_ID]')">[giftwrap_link]</a> </div>
        <!--END: giftwraplink--></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-qty">
      <input type="text" name="qtyitemnum" value="[ITEM_QUANTITY]" size="3" maxlength="5" class="txtBoxStyle" />
      <input type="hidden" name="coliditemnum" value="[ITEM_ID]" size="3" maxlength="5" />
        <div id="itemQty">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['recalculate'].submit();return false;" class="update-qty">[shoppingcart_updatecart]</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-price" id="itemPrice">[ITEM_PRICE] </div>
    <div class="item-total">[ITEM_SUBTOTAL]</div>
    <div class="item-remove"><a href="#" onclick="document.recalculate.qtyitemnum.value=0;document.recalculate.submit();"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!--END: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
  <div class="shoppingCartTotal">
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="item-total">[CARTSUBTOTAL]</div>
    <div class="item-price">[shoppingcart_subtotal]</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--START: DISCOUNTS-->
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="item-total">[DISCOUNTS]</div>
    <div class="item-price">[checkout1_discounts]</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--END: DISCOUNTS-->
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="item-total"><strong>[CARTTOTAL]</strong></div>
    <div class="item-price"><strong>[shoppingcart_total]</strong></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button

```
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
```

Js script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/templates/default-html5/pdf/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script>

var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#itemQty': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {   


   var pdf= new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
  pdf.addHTML($('#contentStart')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });


});

</script>
```

Whole code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='checkout.asp?step=1'" id="vc_ChkButton1" class="btn"><i class="icon-basket"></i> [viewcart_checkout-button]</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <form action="shipquote.asp" method="post" name="shipquote" onSubmit="return submitForm();">
    <input type="hidden" name="thispage" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_zip" value="[shipping_zip]" />
    <script type="text/javascript">document.shipquote.thispage.value = window.location.href;</script>
  </form>
  <form action="recalculate.asp" method="post" name="recalculate" id="recalculate">
    <!--START: SHOPPING_CART_SHIPMENT_INFO-->
    <div class="cart-shipment-info"><span>Ship To [name] [address]</span> 
      <!--START: EDITADDRESS-->
      <div class="button left"><a href='edit_shipment.asp?shipmentid=[shipmentid]&action=editaddresses' class="icon-btn icon-btn-edit">Edit Address</a></div>
      <!--END: EDITADDRESS-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--END: SHOPPING_CART_SHIPMENT_INFO-->
    <div class="shoppingCartItems" id="shoppingCartItems">
      <div class="titles2">
        <div class="item-info">[shoppingcart_items]</div>
        <div class="item-qty">[shoppingcart_quantity]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[shoppingcart_price]</div>
        <div class="item-total">[shoppingcart_total]</div>
        <div class="item-remove">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
        <div id="contentStart">
      <!--START: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item-info">
          <div class="product-image"><!--START: itemthumbnail--><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]"><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" /></a><!--END: itemthumbnail--><!--START: thumbnailnolink--><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" id="tnl" /><!--END: thumbnailnolink--></div>
          <div class="product-name-options"> 
            <!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" class ="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink--> 
            <!--START: itemnamenolink--><span id="spnItemName">[ITEM_NAME]</span><!--END: itemnamenolink--> 
            <!--START: itemoptions--> 
            <br />
            <a href='#' onclick="toggle('opt[ITEM_ID]')">View/Hide options</a><br />
            <div id=opt[ITEM_ID] name=opt[ITEM_ID] style="display:none;">[OPTIONS]</div>
            <!--END: itemoptions--> 
            <!--START: recurring_frequency-->
            <div class="recurring_frequency">This item will Autoship every <strong>[recurring_frequency]</strong></div>
            <!--END: recurring_frequency--> 
            <!--START: giftwraplink-->
            <div class="giftwraplink"> <a onclick="showGiftWrap('[ITEM_ID]')">[giftwrap_link]</a> </div>
            <!--END: giftwraplink--></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-qty">
          <input type="text" name="qtyitemnum" value="[ITEM_QUANTITY]" size="3" maxlength="5" class="txtBoxStyle" />
          <input type="hidden" name="coliditemnum" value="[ITEM_ID]" size="3" maxlength="5" />
            <div id="itemQty">
          <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['recalculate'].submit();return false;" class="update-qty">[shoppingcart_updatecart]</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price" id="itemPrice">[ITEM_PRICE] </div>
        <div class="item-total">[ITEM_SUBTOTAL]</div>
        <div class="item-remove"><a href="#" onclick="document.recalculate.qtyitemnum.value=0;document.recalculate.submit();"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <!--END: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
      <div class="shoppingCartTotal">
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total">[CARTSUBTOTAL]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[shoppingcart_subtotal]</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--START: DISCOUNTS-->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total">[DISCOUNTS]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[checkout1_discounts]</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--END: DISCOUNTS-->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total"><strong>[CARTTOTAL]</strong></div>
        <div class="item-price"><strong>[shoppingcart_total]</strong></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--START: apply_coupon-->
    <div class="applyCoupon pad10 boxShadow">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="checkout-headers">[viewcart_coupon-header]</h3>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="txtBoxStyle" size="14" />
      <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="coupon-msg">[viewcart_coupon-message]</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--END: apply_coupon--> 
    <!--START: ShipQuote-->
    <div class="shipQuote pad10 boxShadow">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="checkout-headers">[viewcart_shipping-header]</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="shipquote-location">
        <input type="text" name="shipping_zip" size="14" value="[shipping_zip]" class="txtBoxStyle" id="calculate_shipping_zip" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn" onclick="document.shipquote.shipping_zip.value=document.recalculate.shipping_zip.value;document.shipquote.submit();" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" id="calculate_button_go"/>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="shipquote-msg">[viewcart_shipping-message]</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!--START: viewcart_ship-->
      <div class="shipquote-result-location">[shipping_city] [shipping_state] [shipping_zip]</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="shipquoteint-action">
        <ul>
          <!--START: Shippers-->
          <li><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> <strong>[OPTION-SHIPPER]</strong> <em>[OPTION-DESCRIPTION]</em> [OPTION-PRICE]</li>
          <!--END: Shippers-->
        </ul>
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Clear" onclick="document.shipquote.action='shipquote.asp?action=clean';document.shipquote.submit();" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" />
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!--END: viewcart_ship--> 
    </div>
    <!--END: ShipQuote--> 
    <!--START: ShipQuoteInternational-->
    <div class="shipQuoteInt pad10 boxShadow">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="checkout-headers">[viewcart_shipping-header]</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="state_countryjs.asp"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_Element(i) {
            return document.getElementById(i) || document.getElementsByName(i).item(0);
        }                               
        function getInternationalQuote() {
            var strAction = "shipquote.asp?shipping_country=" + get_Element("shipping_country").value;
            strAction = strAction + "&shipping_state=" + get_Element("shipping_state").value;
            document.shipquote.action = strAction;

            document.shipquote.shipping_zip.value = document.recalculate.shipping_zip.value
            document.shipquote.submit();
        }
      </script>
      <div class="shipquoteint-location">
        <select name="shipping_country" onchange="this.form.shipping_zip.value='';populateState('shipping_state','shipping_country');" class="txtBoxStyle" id="shipping_country">
        </select>
        <select id="shipping_state" onchange="this.form.shipping_zip.value='';" name="shipping_state" class="txtBoxStyle">
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="shipping_zip" size="14" value="[shipping_zip]" class="txtBoxStyle" id="calculate_shipping_zip" />
      </div>
      <div class="shipquoteint-action">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn" onclick="getInternationalQuote();" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" id="calculate_button_go" />
      </div>
      <div class="shipquoteint-msg">[viewcart_shipping-message]</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!--START: viewcart_ship-->
      <div class="shipquoteint-result-location">[shipping_city] [shipping_state] [shipping_zip]</div>
      <div class="shipquoteint-action">
        <select class="txtBoxStyle">
          <!--START: Shippers-->
          <option><strong>[OPTION-SHIPPER]</strong> <em>[OPTION-DESCRIPTION]</em> [OPTION-PRICE]</option>
          <!--END: Shippers-->
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Clear" onclick="document.shipquote.action='shipquote.asp?action=clean';document.shipquote.submit();" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" />
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!--END: viewcart_ship--> 
    </div>
    <!--END: ShipQuoteInternational-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="chk-buttons"> 
      <!--START: savecart-->
      <a href="myaccount.asp?action=save_cart"><i class="icon-export"></i> [viewcart_save-cart]</a>
      <!--END: savecart-->
      <a href="[continue_url]"><i class="icon-left-open"></i> [viewcart_continue-shopping]</a>
      <!--<button type="submit" name="Add" class="btn"><i class="icon-cw"></i> [shoppingcart_updatecart]</button>-->
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location='checkout.asp?step=1'" id="vc_ChkButton" class="btn"><i class="icon-basket"></i> [viewcart_checkout-button]</button>

  <button type="button" id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="assets/templates/default-html5/pdf/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script>

var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#itemQty': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {   


   var pdf= new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
  pdf.addHTML($('#contentStart')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });


});

</script>
```

Comment: There is no method like addHTML() ,Also add missing js file (html2canvas.min.js)

Comment: I have added the htmlcanvas mine file, and what do you mean there is no method? it seems widely used.

Comment: could you please share the document link ?

Comment: You code is working fine in my console. What error you see in console?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra There is function `addHtml` in jsPDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193487/how-to-use-addhtml-function-in-jspdf

Comment: Also, make sure `$('#cmd').length` gives 1 in console.

Comment: @johndoi2020 , That pdf.addHTML() is available in jspdf.debug.js and not in jspdf.min.js, try to add jspdf.debug.js file

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra is right. jspdf.debug.js would fix the issue provided your event listener and selectors are valid.

Comment: thankyou for the help so far. i've added the whole of my view cart html page at the bottom of my OP. As it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> "the page is only refreshing"

....well, you showed us your button outside its context, but if by any chance it's within a `<form>` it will, by default, cause a full postback of the form. This would seem to be the most likely reason for the page to refresh at that moment.

Change the HTML to

```
<button type="button" id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
```

to avoid this.

(The default setting for the "type" attribute is "submit", which causes a postback when the button is within a form).