# Export URL webpage to PDF in typescript angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to Export a URL to PDF. As shown in the code below, solutionUrl is a link to an article. I want to be able to see the article in the saved pdf file. Right now it only shows the link inside the pdf file.

```js
 component.st: 

 downloadPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(this.solutionUrl, 10, 10 );
    doc.save('Solution.pdf');
  }
```

```html
component.html: 

  <button title="Export to PDF" (click)="downloadPDF()"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with jsPDF but this could be because `doc.text` expects a string as a parameter, not a URL.

Also to display the contents of a HTML page in PDF, you need to use the `doc.addHTML` method

So your code would flow like

1. Get the content of the URL using `this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => parseAndSaveToPDF(res)));`
2. Then define the `parseAndSaveToPDF` function to parse the content of the web page and extract the `body` element
3. Finally use `doc.addHTML(yourParsedBody)` to get the body value as a PDF.

Here is another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193487/how-to-use-addhtml-function-in-jspdf) that might be useful

Comment: I tried your example , it is not working. doc.addHTML doesn't work. Do you know another way to export a url content to pdf?

Comment: @Anjela what happens when you try `doc.addHTML` ?  Is an error thrown or do you get the HTML tags and not the content only?

Comment: I can't use addHTML the way you explained it, i need to use parameters in it and a function.
this is the error message: 
Error: You need either https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas or https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js

Comment: @Anjela yes. that is expected. If you see the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193487/how-to-use-addhtml-function-in-jspdf) I linked to in the answer, it requires you to include one of these two dependencies